# Duplicados en list - django

Tags: django, django-templates

Estoy realizando un proyecto de quiz, en el cual estoy mostrando en el témplate la lista de quiz realizados, pero me esta duplicando el nombre del quiz, se que me esta duplicando el nombre por que tengo dos for, pero existe manera de que solo me muestre una vez el nombre del quiz.

view:

```
@login_required(login_url='testinglogin')
@user_passes_test(is_testing)
def testing_marks_view(request):
    dict = {
        'results': QMODEL.Result.objects.all(),
        'courses': QMODEL.Course.objects.all(),
        'testing': TMODEL.Testing.objects.all(),
    }

    return render(request, 'testing/testing_marks.html', context=dict)
```

Template:

```
 {% for c in courses %}
       {% for r in results %}
             {% if c.id == r.exam_id %}
                 <tr>
                 <td>{{ c.course_name }}</td>

                 <td style="..."><a class="btn btn-success btn-block radio" href="{% url 'check-marks' c.id  %}"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></a></td>

                  </tr>
              {% endif %}
           {% endfor %}
   {% endfor  %}
```

Esta es la lista que me aparece yo tengo un quiz con ese nombre, pero como conteste dos veces el mismo quiz me aparece dos veces
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si solo quieres poner el nombre 1 vez y debajo las rows con los resultados, deberás sacar del 2do for el nombre del examen:

```
{% for c in courses %}
       <p>{{ c.course_name }}</p>
       {% for r in results %}
             {% if c.id == r.exam_id %}
                 <tr>
                 <td style="..."><a class="btn btn-success btn-block radio" href="{% url 'check-marks' c.id  %}"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></a></td>

                  </tr>
              {% endif %}
           {% endfor %}
   {% endfor  %}
```

Por lo que entiendo eso es lo que quieres hacer, la otra sería usar un `distinct()` sobre el diccionario.